# Google Plus Over the Air installs via server-side oauth

Tags: oauth, google-plus, over-the-air

Google released nice feature called [Over-The-Air Installs](https://developers.google.com/+/features/play-installs). But documentation has example only for google's sign-in button.

Checked [Google API PHP Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) and it doesn't have anything related. Tried adding `apppackagename` and `app_package_name` to authorization url - didn't help. Another problem is that Google doesn't enable this feature for all clients.

Is it possible to use it via oauth triggered on server-side? Does Google somehow indicate that you're allowed to use this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently not possible to trigger Over-The-Air Installs using the server-side flow. It is recommended that you use the client-server flow as described and demonstrated in [the quick-start sample apps](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart) instead of using a server-side flow.

You can direct users to install the app at the conclusion of your install by linking to your app in the play store. From the play store, the user could still install your app directly to their device, it would just not happen in the sign-in dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not do it with mixed style. Why Google doesn't allow it via server-side flow?

Comment: I don't know the details for why OTA isn't supported server-side but I'm sure there are many people out there and within Google who want it.  Please add a feature request to the Google+ issue tracker here:

https://developers.google.com/+/support

Answer (score 0):

Even hybrid client-server flow needs to implement the "sign-in button" to your page...
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/client-to-server-flow

Don't know why Google is doing this way!